# Ruby on Rails' "controller.helper" is missing, how to solve it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, view-helpers

If a project is running Rails 2.2.2, and it uses `controller.helper` and the `helper` is not defined, then how can it be solved?  (this is for the Facebooker2 gem http://github.com/mmangino/facebooker2)

details:

error shown:

```
=> Rails 2.2.2 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
Exiting
/Library/
  Ruby/
    Gems/1.8/gems/facebooker2-0.0.5/lib/facebooker2/rails/controller.rb:8:
      in `included': undefined method `helper' for Object:Class (NoMethodError)
```

The code is:   error line is line 8:

```
        controller.helper Facebooker2::Rails::Helpers
```

in the following code:

```
module Facebooker2
  module Rails
    module Controller

      def self.included(controller)
        controller.helper Facebooker2::Rails::Helpers
        controller.helper_method :current_facebook_user
        controller.helper_method :current_facebook_client
        controller.helper_method :facebook_params
      end
```

Comment: My guess is that you aren't calling `include Facebooker2::Rails::Controller` from within a controller derived from `ActionController`.

Comment: I did add: `include Facebooker2::Rails::Controller` to `app/controllers/application.rb` but having that, the error shows (maybe our Rails project was from earlier Rails originally, so it has application.rb instead of application_controller.rb